# Configure mutt and hydroxide for Protonmail

Tags: mutt

I am trying to use my protomail account with mutt.

I installed hydroxide, authenticated in protonmail and started both imap and smtp following [its repo instructions](https://github.com/emersion/hydroxide) like this:

```
$ hydroxide auth LOGIN@protonmail.com
$ hydroxide imap &
$ hydroxide smtp &
```

I also configured `.muttrc` file adding:

```
set ssl_starttls=yes
set ssl_force_tls=yes
set send_charset="us-ascii:utf-8"

set imap_user = "LOGIN@protonmail.com"
set imap_pass = ${my_proton_bridge}

set spoolfile = "imap://localhost:1143/INBOX"
set folder ="imap://${my_proton_bridge}:localhost:1143/"
set postponed = "imap://localhost:1143/[Protonmail]/Drafts"
set mbox = "imap://localhost:1143/[Protonmail]/All Mail"



set smtp_pass = ${imap_pass}
set smtp_url = "smtp://LOGIN@protonmail.com@localhost:1025/"
```

where `${my_bridge_pass}` is the password provided by `hydroxide` when authenticated and of course `LOGIN` is my Protonmail login.

With this configurations I launch mutt, but instead of fetching the emails I read
`Encrypted connection unavailable` in the bottom area. If I run with `mutt -d 5` option (following man page) to get more feedback I get this in `.muttdebug0`:

```
 Using default IMAP port 143
 Using default IMAPS port 993
 Reading imap://localhost:1143/INBOX...
 Looking up localhost...
 Connecting to localhost...
 Connected to localhost:1143 on fd=4
 imap_cmd_step: grew buffer to 512 bytes
 4< * OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR CHILDREN UNSELECT MOVE APPENDLIMIT AUTH=PLAIN] IMAP4rev1 Service Ready
 Handling CAPABILITY
 IMAP queue drained
 4> a0000 STARTTLS^M
 4< a0000 NO TLS support not enabled
 IMAP queue drained
 Encrypted connection unavailable
 mutt_num_postponed: using old IMAP postponed count.
 mutt_index_menu[807]: Got op 167
 mutt_buffer_pool_free: 15 of 15 returned to pool
```

Any ideas? I don't even know where the problem is (a missing mutt configuration, or hydroxide, or some options in protonmail account perhaps ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your configuration.

First, from the hydroxide [README](https://github.com/emersion/hydroxide):

> **IMAP**
>
> For now, it only supports unencrypted local connections.

That means that you need to set...

```
set ssl_starttls=no
set ssl_force_tls=no
```

...which is fine, because you're interacting with hydroxide via `localhost`, so your unencrypted traffic is not traversing any network.

Second, the username for imap and smtp should be *just* your protonmail username, not your email address:

```
set imap_user = "LOGIN"
set smtp_url = "smtp://LOGIN@localhost:1025/"
```

With those changes I think things should work out.